# Browser global storage?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, storage

Is there any browser storage that is the same for all domains, and not dying at the end of session?

How could I set some data using JS and then get it from any page? Like some global cookies or global version of `html5` `localStorage`?

Comment: Sounds like a security vulnerability. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Can you describe a use case scenario?

Comment: @spilio  A number of my web sites want to show ads, but not do the call out to doubleclick etc if the user is logged into my third party site, and we don't want to have to wait for a roundtrip to my third party site to find out if the user is logged in.   (sorry if I'm hijacking the question, it seems like the same thing to me)

Comment: Alan, yes, this is my situation as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like that. Browsers are designed with privacy and security in mind.

You could write a browser extension that provides such behavior.

Comment: Not really, considering web extension storage is completely asynchronous. If you're expecting global data to reliably be in your hands on document start, I've got bad news for you.